# User Control in Webforms

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, title

I have one master page and multiple web forms. I need to give a different title to each of the forms. I was thinking of using a **user control** for that purpose although I am not sure whether it is an elegant and useful solution or not.

1) If it is indeed a good idea, then how to call & use that user control in each of the forms.

2) If it is not useful, maybe someone could advice more apropriate solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have different `.aspx` you could add `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="title"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` between `<title>` and `</title>` tags and then on every `aspx` wrote `<asp:Content id="myTitle" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="title"> My title for this page</asp:Content>` pls let me know if this is your case

Comment: what do you mean by a title?

Comment: Thank you Harry, I used this method and this solution is better over using a label in each of the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this article out](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/interacting-with-the-master-page-from-the-content-page-cs).  You can have a control in the master page that each content page can establish its own title.  You'd have to programmably set it for each page.